# How to implement button effect from Kony Visualizer to Kony Studio?

Tags: user-interface, temenos-quantum

I am just started  using kony, there is somethings that i don't know.

while i build a design inside kony Visualizer and add some effect like button Normal and button Pressed, it work perfectly on kony Visualizer, but when i export and import it on kony Studio, the button effect is gone. like plain design no more effect that showed in Kony Visualizer.

any tips for my problems?

Answer (score 0):

Skins from buttons are not carried over. Try skinning a label or container... I used that instead of buttons.

Comment: so not possible yet for carying from Visualizer? hmm 

yea i tried to reskin it from Studio and make it same like on Visualizer. and yeah it works.